# Difference between servlet url-pattern / and /*

Tags: servlets, web.xml, url-pattern

What is the difference between:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

?

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: You are right...there is no difference :D

Comment: sorry, i had a mistake, update)

Comment: Sorry about earlier, * means all i.e it shall match all requests made.

Comment: @Shashi, thanks and apologies for the misinterpretation. I've made a correction.

Comment: All of above comments saying "no difference" are utterly wrong. Go to the shame corner, you all!

Answer (score 2):

`/` matches only root ie. `http://yourserver/webapplication/`. `/*` matches all requests hitting your application `http://yourserver/webapplication/` as well as `http://yourserver/webapplication/any/path/you/want`

Comment: This answer is utterly wrong. Whoever upvoted this doesn't deserve the title "Java EE developer".

Comment: Then what is the right answer can you please post?

Answer (score -1):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

maps http://server.local/your-application/ to dispatcher servlet

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

maps http://server.local/your-application/%ANYTHING% to dispatcher servlet

Comment: This answer is utterly wrong. Whoever upvoted this doesn't deserve the title "Java EE developer".